# How to set session value in Handler in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, handler

I am using uploadify to upload  a audio file. It uses the handler upload.ashx to upload the file to the server. I want to get the file path in my aspx page. SO I am trying to set a session in handler so that I get the file path in aspx but I am not able to do so. How can I get the value of file path from handler to .aspx page

```
public class Upload : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) { 
       string savepath = context.Server.MapPath(tempPath);
       context.Session["AudioFile"] = savepath;

   }  }
```

Nullreference exception thrown: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 6):

Add [IRequiresSessionState Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx) to your handler definition. Or [IReadOnlySessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx), if you only need read-only info, because this can give a minor performance boost by avoiding locking, and writing back session values.

It's just a marker interface that tells the runtime, that this handler needs session state.

```
public class Upload : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Now I am able to set session value in handler, but in aspx page the session value is always null, why is it null

Comment: And session ID in handler is different from the one I get in aspx page. IS that the problem

Comment: You get different session, and therefore different session ID, if you send a request from different browsers. Or just restart your web server, and request a page, or handler from different tabs. Probably that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add Interface  IRequiresSessionState to your method 
like 
 public class Upload : IHttpHandler,IRequiresSessionState 
{

}

Comment: Could you explain the enhancement over @AkosLukacs 's answer?